# More than 1 Cell range in a With Block in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Simple question. I have to convert data in 2 different columns and the code used will be the same for both columns so instead of writing the code twice can i just "add them together"?

Here is what i wrote with the help of another SO guru :

```
With .Cells(i, 3) And .Cells(i, 5)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        Select Case .Value
            Case Is > 1000000
                .Value = .Value / 1000000 & "Mb"
            Case Is > 1000
                .Value = .Value / 1000 & "kb"
            Case Is > 1
                .Value = .Value & "b"
            Case Else
                .Value = 0
        End Select
    End With
```

i added the `And .Cells(i,5)` part but i am getting an object reference error?

Comment: You can't do that with `With` ;)

Comment: This is when you'll need to use functions! ;)

Comment: @R3uK so do i just need to write a separate bit of code then i guess?

Comment: @R3uK yes, that is my next step... i need to get confortable with vba but that is the end goal

Comment: Rather just write a function and then pass (i,3) and (i,5) to the fucntion that you have written as arguments.

Comment: Why not use 1024 rather than 1000 to be more accurate?

Comment: @RaulGonzales Your logic will return `1000 kb`.  Is that what you want?  Or would you want `1 Mb`?  Also, you could display the same results with custom formatting, and retain the inherent values.

Comment: @TimEdwards  In 1998, the IEC decided that would be `kibibyte` and abbreviate `KiB`.  This was to avoid the inconsistency of `kilo` prefix generally referring to multiples of `1,000` and not `1,024`.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld, wasn't aware. So just to clarify then. 1000 bytes is a KiB and 1024 is a KB? Or have I got it the wrong way round? Every days a school day ;)

Comment: @TimEdwards `kilo` = `1000` = `kb`

Comment: Thanks, I know a kilogramme is 1000 gramms etc. But bytes is to do with 2^10 logic. If I have a file that I hover over which says it's 41.6MB but then use the GetFile.size part of filesystemobject it returns 43646911 bytes. By that logic it should be 43.6MB. Just trying to understand not argue btw... So which should I be referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your main procedure (with the good worksheet object instead of `wS`) :

```
With wS
    Alignment_And_Bytes .Cells(i, 3)
    Alignment_And_Bytes .Cells(i, 5)
End With
```

And the routine that you can reuse (at the bottom of your module for example) ;)

```
Public Sub Alignment_And_Bytes(aCell As Range)
    If aCell.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    With aCell
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        Select Case .Value
            Case Is > 1000000
                .Value = .Value / 1000000 & "Mb"
            Case Is > 1000
                .Value = .Value / 1000 & "kb"
            Case Is > 1
                .Value = .Value & "b"
            Case Else
                .Value = 0
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you are my new best friend mate!